# ListView duplicando os dados na aplicação android

Tags: android, listview

A listView sempre que é carregada duplica os dados, isso acontece se eu sair da aplicação sem encerrar, caso encerre a aplicação funciona normalmente

Sempre que o código `BackTask bt =new BackTask();   bt.execute();` é executado a listView é recarregada e acaba duplicando todos os registros.

Como posso impedir que isso aconteça?

```
 public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //execute background task
    BackTask bt =new BackTask();
    bt.execute();
}

//background process to make a request to server and list product information
private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setTitle("Buscando dados....");
        pd.setMessage("Aguarde!!");
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://testebd.com/getproducts.php");
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // Get our response as a String.
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (pd != null)
                pd.dismiss(); //close the dialog if error occurs
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        //parse json data

        try {
            // Remove unexpected characters that might be added to beginning of the string

            result = result.substring(result.indexOf("["));
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Product p = new Product();
                p.setpName(json_data.getString("nome"));
                p.setEmail(json_data.getString("email"));
                p.setTel(json_data.getString("telefone"));
                p.setOpc(json_data.getString("opcao"));


                records.add(p);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (pd != null) pd.dismiss(); //close dialog
        Log.e("size", records.size() + "");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the ListView to get new records

     }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema tem haver com o chamado [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states).

Durante o seu período de vida uma *Activity* passa por diferentes estados, em cada um deles é chamado o respectivo método do ciclo de vida(*lifecycle callback method*).

A *Task* que preenche a *ListView* é chamada no `onStart()`.

Se observar o seguinte esquema, que apresenta a sequência dos métodos chamados durante o ciclo de vida da *Activity*, verificará que o método `onStart()` é chamado em duas situações diferentes: quando a *Activity* é criada e quando a *Activity* passa do estado ***Stopped***(não visível) para o estado ***Resumed***(visível).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>[fonte da imagem](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states)</sub>

A situação que você refere como *"sair da aplicação sem encerrar"* é aquela em que a *Activity* passa de ***Resumed*** para ***Stopped***.
Quando ela é tornada novamente visível, pela transição do estado ***Stopped*** para ***Resumed***, o método `onStart()` é novamente chamado, fazendo com que sejam duplicados o itens da lista.

A solução proposta pela @Thiago usa um artificio para contornar o problema. No entanto, ela não só obriga a ter de eliminar todos os itens da lista como também fazer uma nova chamada ao serviço externo e criar a lista novamente.

Todo esse *"trabalho"* pode ser evitado se a *Task* for chamada no método `onCreate()`.

Passe este código:

```
//execute background task
BackTask bt =new BackTask();
bt.execute();
```

para dentro do método `onCreate()`. Assim ele será apenas chamado uma vez, quando a *Activity* for criada.

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setTitle("Buscando dados....");
        pd.setMessage("Aguarde!!");
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
       adapter.clear();
    }
```

`adapter.clear();`

Antes de popular a lista, voce irá remover, caso haja algum registro!

Comment: Show!! Funcionou muito bem!

Comment: Isso é aquilo que normalmente se chama de "gambiarra".